# Android Studio Webview Check for URL

Tags: java, android-studio, webview

I just wanted to know how can I execute a specific action when a User navigates to an URL inside a Webview, for Example something like:

```
if (URL == https://google.com) {

    execute Action
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `setWebViewClient`  to override the urls like below -

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if ( url.startsWith("https://google.com")){
         // your action

}
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks this helps